# OpenNMS installation fails with error, Apt-Get broken

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, scripts, dpkg

I was installing OpenNMS and during the install it fails with following error

```
Preparing to unpack .../slpd_1.2.1-9_amd64.deb ...
Stopping OpenSLP server: slpd.
Unpacking slpd (1.2.1-9) over (1.2.1-9) ...
Setting up slpd (1.2.1-9) ...
+ [ configure = configure ]
+ dpkg --compare-versions  le 1.2.1-7.6
+ echo Reinstalling init script for new priorities ...
Reinstalling init script for new priorities ...
+ update-rc.d slpd remove
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/slpd exists during rc.d purge (use -f to force)
dpkg: error processing package slpd (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 slpd
```

Now I can't install or uninstall anything.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo -i
update-rc.d -f slpd remove 
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
```